# Is it possible to programmatically get OTP codes from Oracle Mobile Authenticator

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to get the OTP codes from [this website](https://access.ginniemae.gov/gnma/oma.html) but I am having trouble getting the secret key. The QR code gives the following text:

```
oraclemobileauthenticator://settings?ServiceName::=MyGinnieMae&ServiceType::=SharedSecret&SharedSecretAuthServerType::=HTTPBasicAuthentication&LoginURL::=https://access.ginniemae.gov/oauth2/rest/resources/secretkey
```

And if I go to the link https://access.ginniemae.gov/oauth2/rest/resources/secretkey and tried to log in, I get the following response:

```
{"message": "The secret key can not be read using HTTP basic authentication. Use OAuth to read the secret key.","OICErrorCode": "OAM-92037"}
```

However, I have no idea how to make a proper OAuth request as I dont have the client ID and Secret. Would this be something that the Oracle Authenticator App have, and could this be something I can get?

Can anyone guide me?